# C++: Trying to hook a message box and change its position

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I recently started coding in C++ and I am very new to it. (I code in Javascript, PHP, Java and Obj-C more often)

I'm practicing how to hook a message box and change its position. This is what I have in my .cpp file (after reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530561/set-location-of-messagebox)).

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"User32.lib")
#include <windows.h>

HHOOK hhookCBTProc = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK pfnCBTMsgBoxHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
  if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
  {
    CREATESTRUCT *pcs = ((CBT_CREATEWND *)lParam)->lpcs;
    if ((pcs->style & WS_DLGFRAME) || (pcs->style & WS_POPUP))
    {
      HWND hwnd = (HWND)wParam;
      SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP,130,122, 0, 0,SWP_NOSIZE); 
    }
  }
  return (CallNextHookEx(hhookCBTProc, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

int main(void)
{
  hhookCBTProc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT,pfnCBTMsgBoxHook, 
                                0, GetCurrentThreadId());
  int sResult = MessageBox ( NULL, "Hooked!", "oh my", MB_OK );
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhookCBTProc);
  return 0;

}
```

For some reason the position of the message box isn't changing. Where did it go wrong?

(I know I can create a customized window or dialog. But I am doing it this way because I want to learn how to hook a message box and where I did wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should check in the debugger that your hook is actually being called, if you haven't already.

Secondly, at the time the `HCBT_CREATEWND` hook event is triggered, the window has only just been created - the system has yet to size and position it. It will do this with the values in the `CREATESTRUCT` **after** the hook returns - overriding your `SetWindowPos` call.

See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN on the `lParam` value for this particular hook event:

> Specifies a long pointer to a CBT_CREATEWND structure containing
>   initialization parameters for the window. The parameters include the
>   coordinates and dimensions of the window. By changing these
>   parameters, a CBTProc hook procedure can set the initial size and
>   position of the window.

Therefore, the correct way to use this hook to change a window's position is to modify the values in the `CREATESTRUCT` directly.

Also note that it's quite possible that the dialog manager sizes and positions the window **after** creation, so if you find that this still isn't working for you, you may need to try watching for the `HCBT_MOVESIZE` event instead.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now! But I am too dumb to know how to modify it directly. Can you elaborate on that? Thanks so much!

Comment: E.g. `((LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam)->lpcs->x = 130;`

Comment: Oh thanks so much!! So it can be accessed this way:) Splendid! Greatly appreciate that! But it appears that re-positioning the window this way affects the position of the content in it (the text).How should I align the content to center/ where it used to be ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> At the time of the HCBT_CREATEWND notification, the window has been
>   created, but its final size and position may not have been determined
>   and its parent window may not have been established.

Maybe try hooking into CBT_ACTIVATE instead.